# .mp4 inserted in beamer slide using movie9 appears with black bar on the sides

Tags: beamer

I am currently trying to insert a movie inside a beamer slide deck using the media9 package. The insertion works just fine and I am able to play the movie. However, there is always a black bar around the movie. Here is the entire code:

```
\documentclass[t, 11pt,xcolor=dvipsnames, aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usepackage{media9}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{\textbf{Example of a movie}}    
            \begin{figure}[h]
                \centering
                \includemedia[
                 width=6.5cm,
                 height=5.5cm,
                 keepaspectratio,
                 transparent,              % optionally useful
                 activate=pageopen,
                 playbutton=fancy,
                 addresource=rayleigh-taylor.mp4,
                 flashvars={
                    source=rayleigh-taylor.mp4&autoPlay=true  &scaleMode=letterbox % preserve aspect ratio
                }
                ]{}{VPlayer.swf}
            \end{figure}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The movie file is attached here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rc2rc6cs1yfzjl0/rayleigh-taylor.mp4?dl=0.  I am running this on Mac OS and Manjaro and I have tried Okular and AdobePDF as PDF readers. Both have the same issue.